Get hashcode of a svgfile inside a zip
I have a zip archive containing svg files, I need to get the hash of the content of the svg files and store them so on next execution I can check if the file has been modified or not. My problem is that I get different hashes even though the file wasn't modified
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
{
  using (HashAlgorithm sha1 = SHA1.Create())
  {
    foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
    {
      byte[] hash;
      using (GZipStream svgStream = new GZipStream(entry.Open(), CompressionMode.Decompress))
      {
        hash = sha1.ComputeHash(svgStream);
      }

      documents.Add(new BsonDocument("_id", entry.Name).Add("Hash", hash));
    }
  }
}

collection.InsertMany(documents);

This is the script I run for all the files to store the hashes in a database, when I do the same in my application, the hash returned by the same function is different
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFile)){
  foreach(var entry in archive.Entries)
  {
    using (GZipStream svgStream = new GZipStream(entry.Open(), CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
      var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(svgStream);
      if (hashes.ContainsKey(entry.Name) && hashes[entry.Name].SequenceEqual(hash))
      {
          //code if same hash, never enters here 
      }
      //code if different
   }
 }
}

I am not quite sure if trying to get the hash of this stream is even correct or not
var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(svgStream);


and you're sure hashes  does have the hash for entry.Name and that the code doesn't throw an exception? Because I'm not sure what that  try{} block is doing there.

yes, hashes does have the correct hash, the try{} block I forgot to remove for the sample I added, I will edit that out

The code is wrong unless you double-compress files, which results in a bigger final package. ZIP and GZip are different algorithms. ZIP only works with packages, not streams. SVG files are XML files, ie text. In any case to calculate the hash of each file has the entry stream, don't try to decompress it. Even if you have an SVGZ file, you want the hash of stored files, not the decompression result

@PanagiotisKanavos while that is true, is there something that changes the result of  decompressing a stream with a GzipStream, given the same input stream?

  foreach (var entry in archive.Entries){
    using (GZipStream svgStream = new GZipStream(entry.Open(), CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
      var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(svgStream);
      if (hashes.ContainsKey(entry.Name) && hashes[entry.Name].SequenceEqual(hash))
      {
          //code if same hash, never enters here 
      }
      //code if different
    }
  }
}```
This is the version I have in my application and works fine for whatever I need to do with the content of the files, only hash method is problematic

Should you maybe be using a new SHA1 object per entry?

Can you give a concrete example of hashes computed for the same file by each, and the content of the file?

@AKX I've tried that as well and same result

@Ry- each file is about 100k+ chars

@ValiMoldovan: So make a smaller test file

I did work a bit more on this and I figured out that the reason for different hashes is because in my script I'm using a simple foreach and create the hash for each file, while in my application I have a Parallel.Foreach, I do not understand why they are different but this is the cause

So the foreach you posted in this question isn’t the real code that was running? Anyway, in that case, try what @AKX suggested – SHA1.ComputeHash probably isn’t thread-safe.

@ValiMoldovan Please, next time post the actual code that can reproduce your issue.
